# How should we improve character optimization question tagging?

Tags: discussion

We have the [optimisation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation) tag, but char-op questions are not appearing in char-op searches.

(see [Evaluating your own site - a check for quality](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/evaluating-your-own-site-a-check-for-quality) )

Should we create optimisation tag synonyms for char-op, charop and character-optimization? Or a new tag? or?

Comment: Point of order. Is there a difference between charOp, theoretical charOp, pratical CharOp, and monsterOp? (I know these differences appear in the wizards forums... but..)

Answer (score 3):

Optimization != CharOp.

I think that instead of making a synonym, we find the questions that reference the cb and tag them with CharOp. Same with 3.5 questions. This leaves optimization as a general-case "optimize my X" and char-op reflecting current WotC forum usage. The trivial search for CB strings should provide most of our questions.

Comment: I don't know that anyone knows what these Wizards forum definitions are, nor am I all that inclined to care since this isn't a 4e site...

Comment: @Brian Could you elaborate on what current WotC forum usage *is*? And I assume CB means character builder? When you say "Same with 3.5 questions" do you mean "tag them all as CharOp/char-op" or "do the same to them as is done with 4e?"

Comment: There's a strong differentiation between theoretical opt and practical optimziation. CB means character builder, and we should all tag them charOp or theoreticalCharOp//practicalCharOp

Answer (score 1):

The real problem: SEO for char-op.  Let's add a synonym and tag wiki and that'll help that.

Not a real problem: differentiating between different kinds of op. So far all the optimization questions have been fine with the poster stating their parameters, and frankly a lot of "theoretical" charop will get closed as not a real problem on a SE.

I've added charop, char-op, and optimisation as synonyms for optimization and filled out the tag wiki.

Comment: Does the tag synonym actually help SEO? I searched the page  source of a random optimization question for charop and didn't get any hits.

Comment: To follow up on that: google does not find http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11575/how-do-i-represent-a-warlock-with-a-background-in-thievery with a search for "warlock theivery charop" but does find that question with a search for "warlock theivery optimization" ... though perhaps the newness of the "charop" addition plays into this.

Comment: I don't know how you figure search works, but yes, a change here doesn't automatically propagate to Google immediately.

Comment: But I'm not sure if these things help SEO or not.  We have a little of the same problem with things labeled D&D - we can't go nuts and label everything 20 ways for SEO purposes but I didn't get a good answer from Management on what works - I forget the question number, but we brought it up..

Comment: Looks like tag synonyms have little to no google SEO impact - http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11575/how-do-i-represent-a-warlock-with-a-background-in-thievery is found by http://www.google.ca/search?q=warlock+theivery+optimization but not by http://www.google.ca/search?q=warlock+theivery+char-op (and looking at the HTML source of the question, the synonymous tags are not present)

Comment: And it looks like the question you asked the Stack Overloads is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72372/need-tag-abbreviation-expansion-synonyms-for-seo-purposes

Comment: Yeah they totally ignored me